# oracle regular expression to extract decimal numbers from string

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am trying to extract decimal numbers from a random string. How to do this using regex_replace function? Optionally i want to retain negative sign for negative integers.

example:

input:

```
'text abc023.46'
 '-123.12abc'
```

output:

```
023.46
-123.12
```

Comment: this is not working...select REGEXP_REPLACE('text abc123.46','[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?','') from dual gives output as text abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '-?\d+(\.\d+)?')
FROM yourTable;
```

This pattern also makes the decimal component optional.

Comment: its working as expected. Thank you. Could you please explain the pattern you used.