# Netsuite Technical Consultant

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

how to get an exact number from a string in SQL.
I have a string like '**the total amounts is 12.30 rupees and vat**' in this string i want to extract 12.3 for calculation purposes in SQL, NetSuite formula field

I have tried replace  function to get all numerics from a string but it getting 1230 instead of 12.30 so it is not consider a dot.

Comment: Puzzled how you got from *'Regex to extract a number including decimal places from a string'* to *'Netsuite Technical Consultant'*.

Comment: What if the string is *''the total amount is 12.30 rupees and 1.23 vat'*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Test 12.30 test', '-?\d+(\.\d+)?')
FROM dual;
```

[oracle regular expression to extract decimal numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543188/oracle-regular-expression-to-extract-decimal-numbers-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple regex expression, you can get the numeric value

```sql
select regexp_substr('the total amounts is 12.30 rupees and vat', '\d+\.?\d+?') from dual;
```